# Should jquery preventDefault be used only on anchor tags?

Tags: javascript

Should `preventDefault` be used only on anchor tags?

E.g do I need to add `preventDefault` to a select?

```
$(".select").onchange(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();    
      var value = $(this).attr('value');
      window.location = '?filter=' + value;
});
```

Comment: Exactly why do you need to preventDefault on the select at all?

Comment: @Gearóid - that is exactly what is he asking, does he need to. It is not required and is used on element events that cause a postback; preventing its normal behavior.

Comment: I suppose my question should have been "why do you THINK you need to preventDefault on the select at all?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use `preventDefault` when there is some default behaviour that you want to prevent.

Changing the value of a select element doesn't have any default behaviour.

Clicking a link does. Submitting a form does too. (This is not an exhaustive list)

You might want to run some JavaScript when a link is clicked, and still follow the link.

There is no hard and fast rule for when you use `preventDefault` beyond *when there is some default behaviour that you want to prevent*.

Comment: Ok thanks, just hope no browsers in the future decide to add a  default behaviour for something.

Comment: Why would they? And if they did, how would you know it would be a behaviour you would want to suppress?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default action performed when you select something from a `select` box..

Form submitting (*through the click of a submit button*) is something you might want to also intercept with a `preventDefault`